# Passing multiple values from servlet to jsp onload

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I'm having the below code in the servlet:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<script language=\"javascript\"></script> ");
out.println("<body onload=\"parent.getScriptFrame().PageCheckResponse('" + Value + "');\">");
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

And i'm able to get the `value` from the servlet to the javascript using the below code:

```
function PageCheckResponse(response){
     //code goes here
     init(response);
}
```

The above works for passing a single value.

I would like to know how to pass multiple values from the servlet to JSP onload. WIll passing multiple parameters work? or can 2 different functions be called within the servlet?

Appreciate your pointers on this.

Comment: a better way is to set your values in the servlet as request parameters

Comment: Using JSP and attributes would simplify and clear your code a lot. You should take a look at it ;)

Comment: @BalusC -Yep, never answer a question on a empty stomach

Comment: *" functions be called within the servlet"* : functions are not called from the servlet. Servlet generates an output (HTML in this case, with or without using a JSP) and your javascript function is called from this output.

Comment: @BalusC can you share a link of a sample to see how this can be passed

Answer (score 0):

request.setAttribute("key", "value");